# Making A Solid Mesh Melt?

Tags: animation, physics

I was wanting to make a couple scenes where I have physical meshes melt and no camera fakery. Was wondering if its possible to do within blender?

First scene I need is to have a chocolate bar melt. Needs to stay solid for a good bit and also be animatable for movement and then melt.

Comment: both answers below are good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do it using a ***cloth simulation***, a little bit of ***sculpting*** and ***shape keys***.
[image]

Select your chocolate bar, apply the transformations to it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Rot&Scale*), go to the *Physics* header and press the *Cloth* button. Play with the settings in a *Cloth* panel.
[image]

Select the *plane*, apply the transformations to it as above and press the *Collision* button (remember to place the bar a little bit above it).
[image]

Select the bar and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Wait for the simulation to be finished, then go to the last frame (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>). Go to the *Modifiers* header and press the ***Apply as Shape Key*** button in the *Cloth Modifier* window. Now you have a new *shape key* in the *mesh data* header.
[image]

Now with a *Cloth* shape key selected enable the ***Sculpt Mode***. Use the *Clay* brush to reduce the mesh distortion and the *Grab* brush to shape the melted chocolate bar.
[image]

Use the *Smooth* brush to make the edges smoother. Press <kbd>I</kbd> over the *shape key value* to *keyframe* it. Go to the next frame on the *Timeline*, change the *shape key's* value and keyframe it again.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just have the chocolate bar as a solid object when it is solid. Then, when it needs to melt, use it as a fluid object, and tweak the fluid settings so that it moves really slowly.  You are gonna have to bake the fluid setting at a super high resolution if you don't want it to look like crap up close.