# How can i give a melting vibe to an object?

Tags: modeling

[image]

King of like this, i tried to use the fluid simulation but it does not stick to que object like i want.

Comment: Look at the icing portion here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs  and see if that might help.

Comment: Probably easy to achieve using a cage modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67088/making-a-solid-mesh-melt