# Create paint pour with fluids, needs to fill with a round mesh

Tags: physics

Hello I need the create an effect with fluids where the fluid fills with a perfect circular form. Viscosity must be like paint, see picture below.

[image]

I have tried tweaking the fluids, but I cannot get it to "stick together" as a round form as it fills. All I can get is results as below:

[image]

I have tried to change the resolution, but it only makes the liquid break apart more...

Can anyone point me i the right direction? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the viscosity high (either set the Base and Exponent manually in Fluid World properties or by using the Fluid World 'Viscosity Preset' for Honey (which should be somewhere close to paint)) and then use a Fluid Control object to keep the pool of liquid in the desired shape.

See [How to melt an object then reverse the melt into another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106398/29586) for an example of using Control objects to direct the fluid into a specific shape, using a thin cylinder to shape the pool.