# In Blender 2.9 how to use fluid control?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I have a question about fluid simulation.

In Blender 2.9 how do you express something like the image below?
I downloaded the .blend file posted on the question page below, but it doesn't seem to work in version 2.9.
I've tried harmonics, Fluid flow, Fluid Guide, particle system keys, etc., but it seems difficult.
I'd appreciate if you could answer this question. Thanks for help.

question page
[How to melt an object then reverse the melt into another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106397/how-to-melt-an-object-then-reverse-the-melt-into-another-object)

Image example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlNyl.gif 
https://blender-cg.net/wp-content/uploads/%E7%89%A9%E4%BD%93%E3%81%AE%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%92%E5%BC%95%E5%8A%9B%E3%83%BB%E6%96%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AB%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%951.gif

Comment: you shape that body and use fluid -> geometry and then reverse the animation. I do not understand what is difficult with that? Did you ever make a fluid simulation?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I edited question. And I checked video tutorial about what　you meant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcPV3AkMRLI&list=PLPWFtnb163NUujRYS7NwJ9jACDMFbo7oC&index=4