# From spilled fluid to standing shape: fluid simulation in reverse?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I am trying to animate a solid logo being formed out of spilled fluid, which would basically look something like melting in reverse.

I am currently looking at simply reversing the fluid cache of a "geometry" fluid source bake, but I'd like a more flexible option.

Not fully knowing how to use "fluid guide" force fields may be the key problem here.

For an example of what I'm looking for... [The THX "Calvacade" trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InZOZL9z31U), in the second half, where the shattered pieces of the globe have already been liquefied, and are being pulled into the THX shape.

Shape key and instant disappearance usage at the end is, of course, acceptable.

Comment: This is an old answer but very much related. Newer Blender versions will be different and/or better so not strictly a duplicate. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106398/29586

Comment: @RichSedman There is an effector fluid object type, so I’ll look into that. Thank you :-)