# Control Water Shape in Mantaflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm looking for a way for to 'shape' water into a specific mesh shape - exactly like what [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106397/how-to-melt-an-object-then-reverse-the-melt-into-another-object) post does, but in a more modern version of Blender.

I did find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcPV3AkMRLI), but was very disappointed to see that it's a hacky method of 'just reverse the video once it's done'. As I want the scenes this is used in to be more complex than just text emerging from the floor, this isn't a good example for me.

I've tried messing around with all of the types there are, but nothing seems to work - flow either creates water or takes it away, rather than controlling it, and collision effector + attraction force field sort of works, but still isn't precise enough for what I need. I don't think domain is it either, unless something in the settings would make it easier.

How would you go about doing the example in Mantaflow?